# Haciendo uso del SQL Server Express y SQL Server Management Studio de la manera que diré que lo hice como solucionar el error presentado en el POST?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Realizando el siguiente procedimiento: Haciendo uso de SQL Server 2022 Express Edition Y SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS); luego dando clic derecho en New Query y luego en la ventana que se generó ;copiando este código:

```
    USE [master]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Database [BDBanco_Estudiante]    Script Date: 13/03/2023 4:17:34 p. m. ******/
    CREATE DATABASE [BDBanco_Estudiante]
     CONTAINMENT = NONE
     ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
     LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
     WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
    GO
```

luego ejecutandolo; haciendo clic en el boton Execute que es Eejcutar en Español , sale el error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 10
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'LEDGER'.
```

para solucionar ese problema traté de averiguar como usar LEDGER en SQL ya que era la única idea que tenía sobre que lenguaje de programación estaba usando y como usar el elemento llamado LEDGER por que no se como se denomina en el lenguaje de programación que usé en el código que tengo y que función realiza; y me dí cuenta que lo usaban de estas formas:
después decrear una tabla así:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Asesor](
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Nombre] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [Apellido] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Documento] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Email] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [Telefono] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [Direccion] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [EntidadID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

escribo lo siguiente: ) en el espacio debajo de la tabla y donde empieza la última línea de la tabla; y debajo de eso escribo WITH terminando un espacio antes de empezar a colocar ) y debajo de eso escribo ( donde empezó la primera letra de lo que iba arriba y debajo de eso donde empezó la letra T de lo que iba arriba y lo que dice es SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON, y debajo de eso empezando donde empieza lo que iba arriba escribe LEDGER = ON y no encontré nada m´`as como ven no me ayuda por lo que necesito su ayuda por favor dénme la solución.

Lo que dije que intento hacer en este caso; se va tomar en cuenta en el orden consecutivo; en el sentido de que sirve un orden lógico ;que se plantea escribiendo en el orden exacto; en que van las cosas para darle sentido completo; es: que me digan que debo corregir para que hasta el paso en el que voy; se haga lo que debo hacer para al completar el resto de pasos que faltan para hacer lo siguiente:

crear una base de datos llamada BDBanco_Estudiante haciendo uso de SQL Server 2022 Express Edition y SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) versión 19.0.2

La base de datos debe tener las siguientes tablas:  Cliente, Asesor, Transacciones, operaciones y debo agregar una personal y debe tener estas entidades: 20 registros por entidad en el Modelo de Entidad Relación, la base de datos ya construida debe permitor la consulta y
manipulación de datos en Lenguaje de Definición de Datos. (DDL) y
Lenguaje de Manipulación de Datos. (DML)
• Realizar consultas elementales con la instrucción SELECT
• Realizar consultas haciendo uso del condicional WHERE
• Realizar consultas de ordenamiento con la sentencia ORDER
• Realizar funciones de agregación en SELECT
• Realizar instrucciones con la sentencia GROUP BY
• Así como las combinaciones existentes entre estas para consultas más
específicas.
Se deben incorporar a la base de datos 20 tipos diferentes de consuetas
combinadas a diferentes niveles de complejidad.
Por ejemplo: Lísteme todos los empleados que cumplen años
determinado día, con una lista de empleados permanente;

se logre hacer dicha actividad y para responder eso entenderán que; es menester solucionar el error que se me presentó y eso es lo que pido

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que error?

Comment: gbianchi el código de error fué:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 10 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'LEDGER'

Comment: Yo la reabri.. pero tu pregunta es cada vez mas confusa.. O sea.. solucionaste el problema o no????

Comment: no he solucionado el problema gbianchi, el código que tira error en el programa es el que empieza con:" USE [master]" y termina con" LEDGER = OFF"
GO; y el error es:" Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 10 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'LEDGER'.  "; como lo soluciono gbianchi ?

Comment: Tu publicacion.. es un mareo.. Te tira error eso cuando haces que cosa? al crear la base? sabes que hace LEDGER? realmente lo necesitas?

Comment: gbianchi mañana sigo explicando mi problema por que me voy a acostar ya te agradecería me siguieras ayudando

Comment: lo que yo quiero hacer lo voy a explicar por medio de varios mensajes por que no alcanzo a hacerlo en uno; todos los mensajes que escribiré hasta ahora son parte de loa explicación de lo que quiero hacer y estan en un orden lógico consecutivo en el sentido de que a madida que se avanza en la escritura de las partes de la explicación se va diciéndo la explicación con sentido lógico en el orden exacto en que es escrita lo que yo quiero hacer es crear una base de datos llamada BDBanco_Estudiante haciendo uso de SQL Server 2022 Express Edition y SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) La base de datos

Comment: (DDL) y
Lenguaje de Manipulación de Datos. (DML)
• Realizar consultas elementales con la instrucción SELECT
• Realizar consultas haciendo uso del condicional WHERE
• Realizar consultas de ordenamiento con la sentencia ORDER
• Realizar funciones de agregación en SELECT
• Realizar instrucciones con la sentencia GROUP BY
• Así como las combinaciones existentes entre estas para consultas más
específicas.
Se deben incorporar a la base de datos 20 tipos diferentes de consuetas
combinadas a diferentes niveles de complejidad.
Por ejemplo: Lísteme todos los empleados que cumplen años
deter

Comment: minado día, con una lista de empleados permanentes. Y lo quiero hacer haciendo esto: instalando el SQL Server Express con el método básico e instalarndo el SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) solo dando clic en install luego yo abríiendo SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) en la ventana que me apareció por defecto sin hacer ninguna modificación solo haciendo clic en Connect o Conectar en español dando clic derecho donde dice New Query y luego copiando en la ventana que se generó este codigo:

Comment: USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [BDBanco_Estudiante]    Script Date: 13/03/2023 4:17:34 p. m. ******/
CREATE DATABASE [BDBanco_Estudiante]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 6553

Comment: 36KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT, LEDGER = OFF 
GO

Comment: luego ejecutandolo haicendo clic en el boton Execute que es Eejcutar en Español , el error que sale es:

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 10 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'LEDGER'.

Comment: como lo soluciono ? y como logro mi cometido de lo intneto progrmar ?

Comment: Los comentarios, no son para esto.. lo siento, ni mire la mitad de ellos, todo debe estar en tu pregunta. Y lo otro que quiero saber, es porque directamente no creas la base de datos con las opciones estandar y te olvidas de todo eso que estas escribiendo?????

Comment: gbianchi ya escribí lo que necesito si no entiendes lo que escribí por sintaxis y gramática me lo haces saber que yo la corrijo ( soy capaz de hacerlo, pero no lo he hecho pro falta de tiempo) lo que escribí va para todo el mundo que me quiera ayudar

Comment: SQL server 2019 o 2022? Como puedes observar en el contenido de la pregunta que has escrito, que por cierto incluye el título y las etiquetas, debes poder notar que el desarrollo de lo que escribes en la pregunta no coincide con el resto de la pregunta, que corresponde al título y las etiquetas. Para poder recibir una aproximación o, idealmente, una respuesta al problema expresado en la pregunta que planteas, es necesario que en su conjunto, toda la pregunta mantenga la unidad de cuerpo en objetivo, desarrollo y restricciones, bien sea funcionales o, como en tu caso, no funcionales.

Comment: la edición de SQL Server es 2022

Comment: estoy corrigiendo mi pregunta para que quede bien escrita y con buena graámtica y sintaxis; avisaré cuando la tenga buena del todo

Comment: lo que no entiendo, es porque insistis en crear la db usando codigo, en lugar de usar las herramientas que te da SSMS... eso, no me lo estas contestando...

Comment: la respuesta a la inquietud de; por que insisto en crear la base de datos;usando código,; en lugar de las herramientas de SSMS; se demorará varios mensajes; y diré desde cuando empiezan; empiezan desde ya: por que yo pienso que es imposible; haciendo uso de las herramientas de SSMS y utilizando como incio de código; el código que empieza con USE [master] y termina en GO;tiene que ser si o si usando ese código; crear una base de datos llamada BDBanco_Estudiante haciendo uso de SQL Server 2022 Express Edition y SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) versión 19.0.2, una base de datos con las sig

Comment: uientes tablas:  Cliente, Asesor, Transacciones, operaciones y una personal ; con  20 registros por entidad; en el Modelo de Entidad Relación, la base de datos ya construida debe permitor la consulta y manipulación de datos en Lenguaje de Definición de Datos. (DDL) y Lenguaje de Manipulación de Datos. (DML) • Realizar consultas elementales con la instrucción SELECT • Realizar consultas haciendo uso del condicional WHERE• Realizar consultas de ordenamiento con la sentencia ORDER • Realizar funciones de agregación en SELECT • Realizar instrucciones con la sentencia GROUP BY • Así como las combin

Comment: aciones existentes entre estas para consultas más específicas. Se deben incorporar a la base de datos 20 tipos diferentes de consuetas combinadas a diferentes niveles de complejidad. Por ejemplo: : Lísteme todos los empleados que cumplen años determinado día, con una lista de empleados permanente; Ahí termina la respuesta a tu pregunta; si usted cree que es posible hacer eso; por favor dígame como hacerlo ?

Comment: gianchi me demoré los últimos 3 mensajes que te mandé en responderte tu pregunta; y este mensaje es para todos los que tenían la misma inquietud ?

Comment: Nunca entendiste como funciona la plataforma.. no lo pongas en comentarios.. y no.. no me explicaste porque no podias hacer lo que dice exactamente este [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: gbianchi yo necesito crear la base de datos con el código que dije que usé si o si ósea necesito usar el método Transact-SQL que aparece en el link que me envíaste por eso lo hago como te dije que lo estoy haciendo; he cambiado la pregunta por una muy diferente

Comment: Cambiar la pregunta cuando ya hay intentos de respuesta desnaturaliza el ejercicio que hacen los individuos reunidos en este foro, que es esencialmente entender los pormenores en la descripción de los problemas descritos por cada uno de los invididuos en sus preguntas aquí publicadas. Ontológicamente la pregunta se relaciona de otra forma con los individuos y su ser muta, lo cual no va a ser evidente para ninguno de los que pudiesen pasar por la pregunta y sus respuestas. La unidad de materia de la pregunta, el título, ,las etiquetas y sus intentos de respuesta desaparece y se convierte...

Comment: ...en una nada imposible de asir o atender por parte de los voluntarios que a diario dedican una parte de su tiempo a intentar compartir su conocimiento con los que aquí vienen a compartir sus problemas. En este caso, definitivamente, es requisito sine qua non que las nuevas dudas y los nuevos problemas nacidos de la experiencia personal de quien pregunta deben convertirse en nuevas preguntas autocontenidas, sin el lastre de los intentos de respuesta y todos los comentarios aclaratorios que se han intercambiado en el ejercicio dialéctico que caracteriza a este sitio. Asimismo, debemos...

Comment: ...resaltar que tu pregunta contiene un enunciado sin relación alguna con el resto de la pregunta, en el que se pide construir todo un conjunto de caracteríßticas y funcionalidades que, aunque pueden verse afectadas tangencialmente por el problema expuesto en los errores y el código mostrado, no tienen ninguna relevancia con ellos en tanto afecten los detalles de la resolución para este problema. Que haya que crear veinte consultas es irrelevante para quien descubra cómo corregir este comportamiento inesperado. Espero que estas indicaciones te permitan, ,al fin, escribir una pregunta.

Comment: PD. Ese error indica que el sistema operativo no reporta posibilidad alguna de acceder al recurso indicado por la ruta registrada. Corresponde al usuario ejecutor de la instrucción, es decir usted, comprobar si la ruta es válida en su entorno, hay suficiente espacio en disco para crear el nuevo archivo y el usuario que ejecuta el servicio de SQLSERVER.

Answer (score 0):

Quita la opción "LEDGER = OFF" y se te creara la base de datos, la opción "LEDGER" no existe como propiedad de las bases de datos. La creación de tablas y las instrucciones "SELECT" que describes ya dependen de ti porque se deben definir la columnas y sus correspondiente Tipo de Datos para crear las tablas y en consecuencia los correspondientes "SELECT".
Hare un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES (
    ID        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE    VARCHAR(50),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(128)
)
```

luego la instrucción select:

```
SELECT ID, NOMBRE, DIRECCION FROM CLIENTES;
```

Si no conoces SQL entonces para mas información deberás acudir a la ayuda de este lenguaje.